# Get rid of global variables in library

Tags: c++, class, arduino, global-variables

I'm working on a MIDI controller library that has several classes (e.g. one for pushbuttons, one for potentiometers, one for rotary encoders etc.). All these classes have methods that use a sendMIDI function. There's also a setupMIDI function that is called once at the beginning of the program.
setupMIDI takes three parameters, that need to be accessed by the sendMIDI function.

Definition of classes

```
class Analog {
public:
  Analog (...) { ... }
  void refresh () {
    ...
    sendMIDI(x, y, z, ...);
    ...
  }
}

class Digital { ... (also uses sendMIDI) ... }
etc.
```

setupMIDI and sendMIDI functions

```
byte pin;
int delayTime;
bool debug;

void setupMIDI (byte p, int d, bool db = false) {
  ...
  pin = p; delayTime = d; debug = db;
  ...
}
void sendMIDI ( ... ) {
  ...
  if(debug) ...
  digitalWrite(pin, 1);
  delay(delayTime);
  ...
}
```

Actual program:

```
Analog a1( ... );
Analog a2( ... );
Digital d1( ... );

setupMIDI(13, 10, true);

while(true) {
  a1.refresh(); // calls sendMIDI
  a2.refresh();
  d1.refresh();
}
```

As you can see, all instances of the Analog and Digital classes use  the same sendMIDI function, and this depends on the values entered in the setupMIDI function. The problem is that these values are stored in global variables, which is not ideal.

I've thought about using a MidiSender class, but this would involve passing an instance of it to every Analog or Digital constructor.

Is there a better way to get around this?

Thanks a lot!
Pieter

Comment: Could you clarify this statement: *"[...] in global variables, which is not ideal"*? I agree with the answer below that a *context* wrapping all variables together is certainly better, but I don't see why declaring it globally and passing it by reference is any better than simply have it as a globally accessible **static** resource, at least in the case in which it's meant to be a **singleton**. For instance, the same solution is applied for `Serial.begin(...)`.

Comment: The problem is that the library won't work if the user tries to create a `pin` variable, for example.
Could you point to a link on how to implement something like Serial? Or maybe some search terms?
Thanks!

Comment: well, you could use **namespaces** to resolve name conflict, *imho* it's more a matter of **good design** practice to properly envelope related variables within the same *context* or *instance*. However, **if**  your midi is meant to be a **singleton**, then I don't see anything bad with it being a *global* and *unique* instance. The example of **Serial** is quite easy to follow, look in 'HardwareSerial0.cpp' for its declaration (lines 67-71) and 'HardwareSerial.h/.cpp' for the implementation of the class. The source code is available on **github**:  https://github.com/arduino/Arduino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having a `setupMIDI` function that sets some global variables, have a `MIDIContext` class that stores those values and initializes them via its constructor.

Users of `pin`, `delayTime`, and `debug` will either be *methods* of `MIDIContext` or take a `MIDIContext&` *(`const&` where appropriate)* to access the values.

Example:

```
class MIDIContext
{
private:
    byte pin;
    int delayTime;
    bool debug;

public:
    MIDIContext(byte x_pin, int x_delayTime, bool x_debug) 
        : pin{x_pin}, delayTime{x_delayTime}, debug{x_debug}
    {
    }

    void sendMIDI();
};

class Analog
{
    void refresh (MIDIContext& ctx);
};
```

Possible usage:

```
Analog a1( ... );
Analog a2( ... );
Digital d1( ... );

MIDIContext context(13, 10, true);

while(true) {
  a1.refresh(context);
  a2.refresh(context);
  d1.refresh(context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering if there was an easier way, without having to pass the context as a parameter, but this seems to be the most straightforward method indeed.

Comment: This technique goes a long way to making your code thread safe.